# slice() breaks down javascript Game of Life

Tags: javascript, html, slice, p5.js, conways-game-of-life

My question is about `slice()` in javascript

I was creating my first Game of Life. It finished quite fast but right away I
noticed that it isn't working as it should. I have been trying to debug it
for hours and hours and kind of made it. But it kept bugging me that what
was it that broke it in the first place... The way I was switching the
generations somehow broke the whole logic in weird way that it made my Game of
Life grow out of control in a weird maze looking pattern. Its just a version of
the Game of Life where the user chooses a seed pattern to put in, and click's on
the screen to put it in and start the game.

```
 // Basic vars
    var width, height, life;

    // Seed vars
    var seedPlanted = false;  // Is the game on?
    var seedPos = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    };

    // Different seeds
    var acorn = [
      [0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 1],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 1, 0],
      [0, 0, 1],
      [0, 0, 1],
      [0, 0, 1]
    ];
    var rPentomino = [
      [0, 1, 0],
      [1, 1, 1],
      [1, 0, 0]
    ];
    var dieHard = [
      [0, 1, 0],
      [0, 1, 1],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 1],
      [0, 0, 1]
    ];
    var gosperGliderGun = [
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
      [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ];
    var beeHive = [
      [0, 1, 0],
      [1, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 1],
      [0, 1, 0]
    ];
    var loaf = [
      [0, 1, 0, 0],
      [1, 0, 1, 0],
      [1, 0, 0, 1],
      [0, 1, 1, 0]
    ];
    var toad = [
      [0, 1],
      [1, 1],
      [1, 1],
      [1, 0]
    ];

    // p5 canvas setup
    function setup() {
      width = windowWidth;
      height = windowHeight;
      createCanvas(width, height);
    }

    // Capture user click and set it as the seed position and start the game
    function mouseClicked() {
      if (!seedPlanted) {
        seedPos.x = mouseX;
        seedPos.y = mouseY;
        seedPlanted = true;
        life = new Life(gosperGliderGun, seedPos);  // Initiate the Life object
      }
    }

    // p5 draw
    function draw() {
      background(51);
      if (seedPlanted) {  // Check if the game is on
        life.generate();  // Generate a new generation
        life.display();   // Display the new generation
      }
    }

    // The Life object constuctor
    function Life(seed, pos) {
      this.cellWidth = 4;  // Width of the cells in px
      this.caWidth = Math.ceil(width / this.cellWidth);  // Calculate the grid Width
      this.caHeight = Math.ceil(height / this.cellWidth);// And grid height

      this.curGen = [];  // Declare an array for the current generation 

      // Fill the curGen with arrays full of 0's
      for (var i = 0; i < this.caWidth; i++) {
        this.curGen[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < this.caHeight; j++) {
          this.curGen[i][j] = 0;
        }
      }

      // Apply the seed to the curGen
      pos.x = Math.round(pos.x / this.cellWidth);  // Convert seedPos from px to cells
      pos.y = Math.round(pos.y / this.cellWidth);
      for (var i = 0; i < seed.length; i++) {  // Place the seed to the curGen
        for (var j = 0; j < seed[i].length; j++) {
          this.curGen[(this.caWidth + pos.x + i) % this.caWidth][(this.caHeight + pos.y + j) % this.caHeight] = seed[i][j];
        }
      }

      // Create and fill the nextGen array variable with empty arrays
      this.nextGen = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < this.caWidth; i++) {
        this.nextGen[i] = [];
      }

      // Generate a new generation
      this.generate = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.caWidth; i++) {  // Loop through the cells
          for (var j = 0; j < this.caHeight; j++) {
            var neighbors = 0;
            for (var k = -1; k <= 1; k++) { // At every cell, loop through its neighbors in a 3x3 grid
              for (var l = -1; l <= 1; l++) {
                // Count the neighbors and wrap aroundthe edges with "modulo trick"
                neighbors += this.curGen[(this.caWidth + i + k) % this.caWidth][(this.caHeight + j + l) % this.caHeight];
              }
            }
            neighbors -= this.curGen[i][j];  // Subract the cell itself from the neighbors

            // Rules of survival and birth
            if (this.curGen[i][j] === 1 && neighbors < 2) { // Underpopulation
              this.nextGen[i][j] = 0;
            } else if (this.curGen[i][j] === 1 && neighbors > 3) { // Overpopulation
              this.nextGen[i][j] = 0;
            } else if (this.curGen[i][j] === 0 && neighbors === 3) { // Reproduction
              this.nextGen[i][j] = 1;
            } else { // Stasis
              this.nextGen[i][j] = this.curGen[i][j];
            }
          }
        }
```

Here is the problem part. Now I have to just set the newly created generation as
the current generation so that it will be displayed and generated from.
My first thought was to use the slice() to slice off the info from the
new nextGen and put it in the old curGen. Then I can write on top of the nextGen
in the next round. This seemed to a rookie like me to work, but it created
some weird out of control growing and disappearing. I went through all the loops
and arrays and drew all kinds of things on the screen to understand what isn't
working. I found out that the neighbors were not counted correctly somehow and
it it made the basic stable seeds like the "toad" to disappear.

Then I went to get other examples how others had done it, and this "swap"
method in p5js.org examples of Game of life caught my eye, where you just swap
the generations with the help of a temporary variable to hold the other for a
moment. And somehow this made the same logic to work. I dont understand why.
Then I tried to fix my old method to just write 0's on top of the vain nextGen.
Didn't work. Then I tried to write it full of fresh arrays and it worked. I dont
understand why the swap method worked leaving the other array full of old states
waiting to be overwritten, and the slice() method leaving the same old states to
be overwritten to the other array didn't work. Unless I wrote it full of new
arrays. Does the slice() function leave some reference to the old array or somehing?

If you uncomment the *FastFix* line it will work,

or if you uncomment the three "swap" method lines, and comment out the slice()
method with the following for loop. It will work. But not with only the slice().

Can someone tell me why? What does the slice() do that the "swap" doesn't?

```
  //var temp = this.curGen;             //
    //this.curGen = this.nextGen;         // Why this "swap" method works?
    //this.nextGen = temp;                //

    this.curGen = this.nextGen.slice(0);  // And this slice() not?

    for (var i = 0; i < this.caWidth; i++) {    // This
      //this.nextGen[i] = [];  //<---*FastFix*  // is all
      for (var j = 0; j < this.caHeight; j++) { // a fix that I
        this.nextGen[i][j] = 0;                 // that I tried.
      }                                         // But it wont
    }                                           // work without
  }                                             // the *FastFix*
                                                // which is a
                                                // stupid hack


 // Display the cells
  this.display = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.caWidth; i++) {  // Loop through the cells
      for (var j = 0; j < this.caHeight; j++) {
        noStroke();
        if (this.curGen[i][j] == 1) {  // Decide fill based on the cell state
          fill(255);
        } else {
          fill(51);
        }
        rect(i * this.cellWidth, j * this.cellWidth, this.cellWidth, this.cellWidth);  // And draw it
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.0/p5.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="libraries/p5.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="life.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Isn't the slice method only assign the copy of nextGen to curGen? The nextGen value will remain the same.

Comment: Why have you formatted your question too as code?

Comment: Sorry I'm really bad at this cause I haven't asked questions here almost at all and wasn't familiar to the formatting interface. :o I try to edit the question better :o

Comment: And Kendrick Kesley yes thats what I'm doing. I figured it would not matter that what is inside the nextGen after the "generation change" because it will get overwritten in the next generate() function. Wouldn't it matter only that the two 2D arrays are the same proper size? :o